# How to receive form elements and order them according to the MLA and APA format with js or php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to put an add source section on my website. For this, I need to convert text type inputs as name, author, page, date, publisher into the MLA and APA format style. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the concatenation operator (`+`). Or, if you have ES6 features available, then I would use template strings.

Example for books (format: Last Name, First Name. Book Title. Publisher City: Publisher Name, Year Published. Medium.):

```
function convertToCitation() {
  var lastName = yourForm.lastName.value;
  var firstName = yourForm.firstName.value;
  var bookTitle = yourForm.bookTitle.value;
  var publisherCity = yourForm.publisherCity.value;
  // ... repeat for all the other fields

  return lastName + ', ' + firstName + '. ' + bookTitle + '. '
  // ... repeat for all the other fields

  // Or, if you have ES6 available...
  return `${lastName}, ${firstName}. ${bookTitle}.....repeat for other fields`;
}
```